# Python (boto) TypeError launching Spark Cluster

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-spark, boto

Following is attempt to launch cluster with ten slaves.

```
12:13:44/sparkup $ec2/spark-ec2 -k sparkeast -i ~/.ssh/myPem.pem \
          -s 10  -z us-east-1a -r us-east-1 launch spark2
```

Here is output.  Note that the same command had been successful with the February Master code. Today I had updated to latest 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT

```
Setting up security groups...
Searching for existing cluster spark2 in region us-east-1...
Spark AMI: ami-5bb18832
Launching instances...
Launched 10 slaves in us-east-1a, regid = r-68a0ae82
Launched master in us-east-1a, regid = r-6ea0ae84
Waiting for AWS to propagate instance metadata...
Waiting for cluster to enter 'ssh-ready' state.........unable to load cexceptions
TypeError
p0
(S''
p1
tp2
Rp3
(dp4
S'child_traceback'
p5
S'Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1280, in _execute_child\n    sys.stderr.write("%s %s (env=%s)\\n" %(executable, \' \'.join(args), \' \'.join(env)))\nTypeError\n'
p6
sb.Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ec2/spark_ec2.py", line 1444, in <module>
    main()
  File "ec2/spark_ec2.py", line 1436, in main
    real_main()
  File "ec2/spark_ec2.py", line 1270, in real_main
    cluster_state='ssh-ready'
  File "ec2/spark_ec2.py", line 869, in wait_for_cluster_state
    is_cluster_ssh_available(cluster_instances, opts):
  File "ec2/spark_ec2.py", line 833, in is_cluster_ssh_available
    if not is_ssh_available(host=dns_name, opts=opts):
  File "ec2/spark_ec2.py", line 807, in is_ssh_available
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT  # we pipe stderr through stdout to preserve output order
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1328, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception
TypeError
```

The AWS console shows that instances are actually running. So it is unclear what actually failed.

[image]
Any hints or workarounds appreciated.

**UPDATE** This same error occurs when doing **login** command. It seems to be problem with the boto API - but the cluster itself appears to be OK.

```
ec2/spark-ec2  -i ~/.ssh/sparkeast.pem  login spark2
Searching for existing cluster spark2 in region us-east-1...
Found 1 master, 10 slaves.
Logging into master ec2-54-87-46-170.compute-1.amazonaws.com...
unable to load cexceptions
TypeError
p0
(..  same exception stacktrace as above )
```

Comment: I don't know anything about the ``spark_ec2`` module you are using but from the stack trace it doesn't seem to be doing anything related to boto when the error occurs.  It looks like it is waiting for SSH to respond on the instances.

Comment: @garnaat - Yup, it looks more like something is going wrong with the `subprocess` call that invokes `ssh`. javadba - Is your `ssh` executable OK?

Comment: re: ssh  I have other ssh windows open and open/close ssh windows a number of times every day. I had also connected to AWS a number of times , most recently using the February spark codebase.  Just to be sure, I just opened ssh to a partner's cluster and it is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that the python-2.7.6 installation on my yosemite macbook appears to have become corrupted.

I reset the PATH and PYTHONPATH to point to a custom homebrew installed python version and then the boto - and other python commands including building spark performance project -  work fine.